# IDropTarget with x64

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, com, ole

I Implemented file dropping based on a [drop target class sample from catch22.net](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/drop-target). Everything works fine on 32-Bit - but nothing works in my x64-Bit version.

```
HRESULT __stdcall CDropTarget::QueryInterface (REFIID iid, void ** ppvObject)
```

is not called when calling

```
pDropTarget = new CDropTarget(hwnd);

CoLockObjectExternal(myDropTarget, TRUE, FALSE);
```

as it is in the 32-Bit version. The problem occurs on XP and Windows 7. I am using VS 2010.

Whats the problem?

Comment: Since you are using VS 2010, you can probably use the solution at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18935/The-most-complete-C-Webbrowser-wrapper-control I have VS 2005 so I can't use that solution, but thanks to your post I can now get it to work by using a 32-bit machine.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? When you try to drop over a window of a 64bit app you don't get the "drop" icon or what? be more specific...

Comment: Yes i get the icon for "not allowed". Releasing the mouse in the Drop target window has no effect. No drop messages are received.